# Как добавить Fragment во ViewPager?

Tags: android

У меня имеется ViewPager для пролистывания TextView, которые он берет из массива. Все работает замечательно, но сейчас необходимо добавить Fragment с реализацией кнопки. Кнопку я реализовал, работает стабильно. Но у меня не получается вставить эту кнопку (Fragment) во ViewPager. У кого какие идеи?Комменты приветствуются! +1 к карме)

**ViewPager** - отвечает непосредственно за пролистывание.

```
public class SwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

private int[] car = {R.string.car1, R.string.car2,
        R.string.car3, R.string.car4, R.string.car5};
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public SwipeAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return car.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return (view==(RelativeLayout)object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.carSwipe, container, false);

     TextView textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.interTextView);
    textView.setText(car[position]);
    container.addView(itemView);
    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((RelativeLayout)object);
}
```

**Button** - отвечает за распознавание голоса и вывод его в TextView

```
public class ButtonFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button, container, false);
    Button recognizeButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    recognizeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "You may speak!");
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> results;
        results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        TextView speechText = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView);
        String str = "";
        speechText.setText(str);
}
}
    }
```

**Layouts**

voice_rec.xml кнопка фрагмента

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="recognition"
        android:id="@+id/buttonRec"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**text_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge">
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <fragment
            android:name="com.example.nikolai.viewpagerstartandroid.ButtonFragment"
            android:id="@+id/button_fragment"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            tools:layout="@layout/button">
        </fragment>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо использовать `FragmentPagerAdapter` вместо `PagerAdapter`. Соответственно придётся и остальные страницы переделать во фрагменты. Сделать `ViewPager` с обычными вью и фрагментами, наверное, можно, но лучше даже не пытаться.

Вот простейший вариант адаптера с фрагментами:

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        switch(pos) {

        case 0: return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
        case 1: return SecondFragment.newInstance("SecondFragment, Instance 1");
        case 2: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 1");
        case 3: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 2");
        case 4: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 3");
        default: return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Default");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }       
}
```

Вот подробно на [англо-саксонском](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18413437/3212712)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! +1)  Если я пойду по этому пути, создавая активити под каждое слово, насколько я понял, то это наверняка существенно утяжелит мое приложение. Я прав?

Comment: @Nikolai, ну, вы будите фрагменты, а не активити создавать... И пайджер по умолчанию загружает в память только 3 фрагмента. Засим особого снижения производительности не будет, а вот удобств с таким подходом гораздо больше, чем при использовании вьюх в качестве страниц.

Comment: скажите Юрий, я могу использовать для всех Fragments один layout c TextView, подставляя значения из string, и один с ViewPager для FragmentPagerAdapter? У меня запускается и работает, но не скажется ли это на работе или на чем-то ещё? Меня настораживает тот факт, что в примере каждый фрагмент имеет свой layout. Хотя, можно былобы использовать один layout и передовать на него разные значения.

Comment: @Nikolai, фрагменты могут быть любые - все одинаковые или все разные. Можно в каждом свою разметку иметь, а можно везде одинаковую - одно тестовое поле и всё. Тут вы никак и ничем не ограничены. Для однотипных фрагментов можно иметь одну разметку и просто менять в ней текст в зависимости от порядкового номера фрагмента в адаптере.

Comment: Сапсибо, за объяснение!